# php parallel payment - transaction fee

Tags: php, paypal

How can i achieve this below scenario? taken fron payPal site.

Receiver Pays the Fee in a Parallel Payment

If the receivers pay the fee in a parallel payment, each receiver pays a portion of the fee, based on their assessment. The following example shows the receivers paying the fees:

[image]

My paremeters:

```
$bodyParams = array (   
                        "actionType"                        => "PAY",
                        "currencyCode"                      => "USD",
                        "receiverList.receiver(0).email"    => $receiver_p,
                        "receiverList.receiver(0).amount"   => $amount_primary,
                        //"receiverList.receiver(0).primary"=>true,
                        "receiverList.receiver(1).email"    => $receiver["paypal_id"][0],
                        "receiverList.receiver(1).amount"   => $amount[0],
                        "receiverList.receiver(2).email"    => $receiver["paypal_id"][1],
                        "receiverList.receiver(2).amount"   => $amount[1],                      
                            "receiverList.receiver(3).email"    => $receiver["paypal_id"][2],
                        "receiverList.receiver(3).amount"   => $amount[2],                  
                            "receiverList.receiver(4).email"    => $receiver["paypal_id"][3],
                        "receiverList.receiver(4).amount"   => $amount[3],                      
                        "returnUrl"                         => APP_WEB_ROOT.'/checkout.php?cmd=paid',
                        "cancelUrl"                         => APP_WEB_ROOT.'/checkout.php',
                        "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage"     => "en_US",
                        'FeesPayer' => 'EACHRECEIVER'
                    );
```

is `'FeesPayer' => 'EACHRECEIVER'` is enough parameter to pass to achive the above scenario. how can i check this in sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, EACHRECEIVER is what you want.  You can test this in the sandbox by creating multiple sandbox accounts and then setting up a payment that gets split among those receivers.  When you complete that checkout in the sandbox you could then login to each receiver account and see the fee they paid.